# Guardar pdf en otra carpeta con jspdf en Angular

Tags: angular, jspdf

quisiera saber si hay una forma de guardar mi pdf generado con jspdf en otra ruta, he intentado cambiar el metodo save

```
doc.save('C:\Users\soporte-papo\Documents\certificado.pdf');
```

pero este solo me modifica el nombre.
con jspdf tengo la facilidad de modificar la ruta ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que desea hacer no es posible por razones de seguridad. El navegador es quien decide dónde y cómo se guarda un fichero descargado, el programador web solo puede "sugerir" un nombre para el fichero, pero nunca un camino directo para salvarlo.